# Which CPu and GPU to use for Blender?

Tags: graphics-cards, processor

I'm looking to buy a computer to do blender mainly 3D modelling and animations and would like to know what is the best mix of CPU and GPU for these needs.

CPU:

```
Intel Core I7 11700K
AMD Ryzen 5 5600X
AMD Ryzen 7 5800X
```

GPU:

```
NVidia GeForce RTX 3060 TI
NVidia Geforce RTX 3070
NVidia Geforce RTX 3070 TI
```

Which of these has the best value for money ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

I think Ryzen 7 and 3070 would be a great combo with 32GB of ram.